# CSS margin issues only in Chrome & Safari

Tags: css, layout, google-chrome, safari, padding

I'm finishing up my first site: http://www.audio-agent.com/.

I just noticed that, while it looks correct in Firefox, the navigation menu padding and vertical alignment is off when viewed in Safari / Chrome.

Here's all the CSS I'm using for the menu:

```
ul#navigation {
background:url(images/navBgSlice.png);
color:#fff;
padding:6px 40px 6px 40px;
font-size:14px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:right;
}

ul#navigation a.current {
color:#fcff00;
}

ul#navigation a:link, ul#navigation a:visited,
p.flip a:link, p.flip a:visited {
font-weight:normal;
}

ul#navigation a:active, ul#navigation a:hover,
p.flip a:active, p.flip a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}

ul#navigation li {
display:inline-block;
padding:0 10px;
}

ul#navigation li:last-child {
padding-right:0;
}
```

And the HTML is just:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <a class="current" href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>"><li>Services</li></a> |
    <a href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>/clients"><li>Clients</li></a> |
    <a href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>/news"><li>News</li></a>
</ul>
```

Any idea what could be going on? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change:**

```
ul#navigation li:last-child {
padding-right:0;
}
```

**To:**

```
ul#navigation li.last-child {
padding-right:0;
}
```

And add class="last-child" to your list:

`<a href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>/news"><li class="last-child">News</li></a>`

If you want full cross-browser support, this is the simplest way to accomplish this - As earlier IE and Safari struggle with the pseudoclass `:last-child`

Hope this helps.

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/DAyjz/

Comment: @True North Creative: Thanks, that appears to be the problem! But now my padding isn't eliminated on the far right navigation item. Not a huge issue, but is there any way to keep that functional?

Comment: Edited my post to get you straight.

Comment: @True North Creative: Alright, that will work. Thanks for your help!